# Return html element in browser by clicking a button

Tags: reactjs

newBlock.js

```js
function NewBlock() {

    function p() {
        alert('hello world')
    }

    function h() {
        return <h1>Hello world</h1>
    }


   return(
    <div>
        <button onClick={p}>Paragraph</button>
        <button onClick={h}>Heading</button>
    </div>
   ) 
}
```

textEditor.js

```js
  <NewBlock />
```

How can I make it when user clicks `Heading` button to return `Hello World` in the HTML browser?

Comment: Can use some kind of toggle in state and then with the help of button click change the toggle value

Answer (score 0):

Since you were using a function so I used hooks for the state. With the help of the previous state, I was able to invert the boolean value of toggle on the button click.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

export default function App() {

  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true);

  function h() {
      setToggle(prevState => !prevState)
  }

return(
  <div>
      <button onClick={h}>Heading</button>
      {toggle ? (<h1>Hello world</h1>) : null}
  </div>
  ) 
}
```

[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-button-toggle-o0jmq)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,

```
function App() {
    const [heading, setHeading] = useState('Heading')

    function p() {
        alert('hello world')
    }

    function h() {
        setHeading('Hello World')
    }


   return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={p}>Paragraph</button>
            <button onClick={h}>{heading}</button>
        </div>
   ) 
}
```